# Clojure: Simplifying Logical Expressions Using Several Arguments

Tags: clojure, functional-programming, logic

I am new to Clojure and attempting to write a program that is supposed to simplify logical expressions. For example:

```
(or x false) => x
(or true x) => true
(or x y z) => (or x(or y z))
```

I believe, that I have figured out how to simplify expressions up to two arguments. However, I don't know how to simplify expressions that consist of more than two arguments. I attempted to use the nth function to try and partition the expression, but that seems to complicate things further:

```
(defn pre-simplify [expression n]
  (cond
    (= n 0) (nth expression 0)
    (= n 1) (nth expression 1)
    (= n 2) (nth expression 2)
    (= n 3) (nth expression 3)
   )
)
```

This is the code for the Simplify Function:

```
(defn simplify
  ([op arg1]                                                
    (cond
      (and (= arg1 'true) (= op 'not)) false
      (and (= arg1 'false) (= op 'not)) true
      (= arg1 'true) true
      (= arg1 'false) false)
      ;not not x -> x
    )
  ([op arg1 arg2]                                         
    (cond
      (seq? arg1) (let [arg1 (simplify op arg1)]))
    (cond
      (seq? arg2) (let [arg2 (simplify op arg2)]))
    (cond
      (= op 'or) (
                 (cond
                    (and (= arg1 'false) (= arg2 'false)) false
                    (or (= arg1 'true) (= arg2 'true)) true
                    (and (= arg1 'false) (and (not= arg2 'false) (not= arg2 'true))) arg2
                    (and ((not= arg1 'false) (not= arg1 'true)) (= arg2 'false)) arg1
                )
              )
      (= op 'and') (
                   (cond
                     (and (= arg1 'true) (= arg2 'true)) true
                     (or (= arg1 'false) (= arg2 'false)) false
                     (and (= arg1 'false) (and (not= arg2 'false) (not= arg2 'true))) arg2
                     (and ((not= arg1 'false) (not= arg1 'true)) (= arg2 'false)) arg1
                   )
             )
       )
 )
```

Also, I am thinking of using recursion on the rest of the list after the first two arguments. For example, this is how I am attempting to do it on more than two arguments:

```
    ([op arg1 arg2 & rest]                                    
      (simplify op (list (op arg1 (op arg2 rest))))))
```

Comment: What are the 3 `cond`s in a row supposed to do? I might be tired, but the first 2 should have 0 effect on anything. You're creating a local shadow of `arg1` and `arg2`, then throwing it away.

Comment: Are you coming from imperative programming by chance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like homework, so let me just invite you to consider the problem from another angle.

In Clojure,

- an `and` expression is a list (or other sequence) of expressions that starts with the symbol `'and`;
- an `or` expression is a list of expressions that starts with the
  symbol `'or`;
- ... .

An expression may also be

- a symbol for an argument or other local name, or
- the literal `true` or `false`.

To `simplify` an expression:

- If it's a sequence (use `seq?` to test this), `simplify` its
  arguments (all the elements of the list but the `first` - `rest` will give you those). You can use `map` to make the recursive call.
- Then, for example, if the operator (the `first` element) is an `and` symbol,

  - If there are any `false` literals among the operands (you can use
    `some` to test this), replace the whole expression with `false`.
  - If not, `remove` any `true` literals.

These simplifications may open the way for others. For example,

- `(and)` is just `true` and
- `(and x)` is just `x`.

Whatever you do, test your function as you develop it, making sure it does what you think it does. I got caught leaving out the operator in one case. And I fell over the `(and x)` case.

What's also up for grabs is how and how far you are expected to verify that the expression is valid.

- What about unknown operators?
- Are you expected to verify that symbols refer to something. If so,
  how?

*Notes*

- I'm assuming we can ignore side effects: all the expression does is
  return a value.
- I wouldn't replace `(or x y z)` with `(or x (or y z))`. This achieves
  nothing and uses an extra token: the opposite of simplification.
- Any Clojure value - a number, even a function - acts as logically
  true, except `false` and `nil`, which act as logically false. Whether
  this is relevant to your problem, I don't know.
- If you're feeling smart, you may be able to parameterise how `and`
  and `or` behave in terms of the literal you ignore (`true` and
  `false` respectively), the one you conclude with, and the one you return
  when there are no arguments.

The problem as whole is considered intractable. If you find an efficient solution to it, you'll be world famous!